# Is it true that for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^+$ there is $K \in \mathbb{R}^+_{< \infty}$ s.t. $(Kx)^{\alpha} \geq (1+x)^{\alpha}$ for $x \geq x_0$?

Tags: calculus

My problem is what the title suggests and I do appreciate any hints to get me started. I feel like I should be looking at zeros of the equality $$(Kx)^{\alpha} = (1+x)^{\alpha}$$ and then convince myself (and others) that the derivative of the first is greater for some selected $K$, however this approach could be wrong or done more efficiently.

Just to be clear, the $x_0$ I choose to denote as the zero, or the point in the positive reals, for which greater values of $x$ the inequality holds.

Comment: Yes of course---the left-hand side grows like $K^\alpha x^\alpha$, whereas the right-hand side grows like $x^\alpha$. The left-hand side has to eventually "win" (provided $K^\alpha > 1$).

Comment: As for hints: your proposed idea is fine, if maybe a bit algebraically awkward (in some way it's kind of the same as the original problem, only with exponent $\alpha - 1$). A fairly heuristic way (and fine if you don't care about what exactly $x_0$ is) could be to look at the limit of their quotient.

Comment: @prets I didn't think of the quotient, I will try it immediately, thank you.

Comment: Is it meaningful to specify the $<\infty$ in $\mathbb{R}^+_{< \infty}$?

Comment: @Adam Neeley I want the constant $K$ to be finite, that is that the equality should hold for $K \neq \infty$. Perhaps false notation, but this is the reason why I chose it.

Comment: For what it's worth: had the question been phrased "there is a constant $K$ such that ..." I don't think anyone would've misunderstood, let alone said "well of course $K = \infty$ works!" unless they were being deliberately cheeky.

Comment: I only bring it up because $\infty \notin \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question is deceptively simple.

It's asking to prove the following:

$$\forall \alpha \in \mathbb R, \exists K\in \mathbb R \text{ s.t. } (Kx)^\alpha \ge (1+x)^\alpha$$

Here's my scratchwork:

$(Kx)^\alpha \ge (1+x)^\alpha$

$\implies Kx \ge 1+x$

$\implies K \ge \frac{1+x}{x}$.

Hint: Let $K \ge \frac{1+x}{x}$.